# Share content of ListView

Tags: android, share

With `Android Studio` I created a `Button` in my `xml` file and I want to share the content of my custom `ListView` by clicking on it. 
The problem is that after I click it nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

`CustomList.class`:

```
Button btn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("text/plain");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtTitle2.getText().toString());
           intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share via...");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));

        }
```

this is the `xml`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_share"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is almost right. I assume that you're doing that work inside the adapter.
Try removing the line

```
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share via...");
```

The code below runs like a charm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_app));
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    intent,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.share_via)
                )
            );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to share the text content I have in my  `CustomAdapter` that is  `txtTitle2` I have in  `getView`. Any ideas?

Comment: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtTitle2.getText().toString());      I suppose you're setting the reference to "txtTitle2" properly. Something like: final EditText txtTitle2 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle2Id);    'cause otherwise the recycled view can prevent you from getting the correct reference.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:onClick="onClick"` to your XML , it should solve the purpose

And if you want to read more read this [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: I added that but nothing changed

Comment: Is there any permission I'm missing?